# Return a char* from C, but empty in PHP

Tags: php, c, swig

I am new to SWIG.
My problem is as follows:

I have written a function in C which return a `char*`,
say:

```
char msg[100];
strcpy(msg,"helloworld");
char* foo(){
return msg;
}
```

I can see the message "helloworld" when I run it in C.
The problem is when I call this method (which is generated by SWIG from my interface file into a PHP file) from PHP as:

```
$msg = foo();
```

`$msg` always has `String(0)=""` when var_dumped.

To debug this, I also did:

1. Wrote this message every time into a file.
2. Read the same file from PHP.

This works. But I wanted to get the message by directly calling `foo()`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need a persistent allocation of msg. Either make it a global or do a malloc/new of the memory for it.  It looks like you are simply allocating it on the stack as a local variable in that function. The pointer to the stack that you return will point to garbage as soon as the function returns.

Comment: No he's not. The array is not local.

Comment: You're right. I missed where foo started reading on the phone.